# Dealing with quality control comments

Tags: discussion, comment

I contributed an answer to [Is arrow notation for vectors "not mathematically mature"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093696/is-arrow-notation-for-vectors-not-mathematically-mature/1093725#1093725), that, much to my surprise, has received lots of votes. However, someone whose profile says that they are engaged in quality control on MSE has made some critical comments that I dispute and that are phrased in rather hostile terms: "... absurd that this answer got 121 upvotes ...", "... platitude ...", "[something else] ... does have some content". I don't mind debate, but I understand that comments on MSE are not a place to have extended debates. So how should I react?

Comment: Thanks to the rapid reactor who voted to close this question. Why is it off-topic?

Comment: if you feel that some comments are offensive / unconstructive — there are comment flag reasons exactly for that — or just 'keep calm and carry on'

Comment: My preferred solution here is to close and delete the question, thus resolving any issues of the worthiness of upvotes.

Comment: @Grigory M: thanks. That's a useful tip.

Comment: @Fundamental: you've lost me. My concern was not with the number of upvotes, but with subsequent criticism of my answer.

Comment: @RobArthan Someone (possibly known to you) may be be purposely voting against your posts (such as this one). Flagging should solve the problem.

Comment: That such user operates under a misguided stance that votes should be approximately balanced between upvotes and downvotes and selectively chooses to ignore the fact that the entire StackExchange platform is designed to encourage upvotes as a feedback mechanism to promote participation. There is no way to convince the user otherwise, unfortunately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flagging comments that are genuinely offensive and/or not constructive as such is probably the best response.  At a guess, I think that already happened here and those comments were flagged enough to cause them to disappear (deleted).